# How to figure out an equation from a plot?

Tags: programming, recreational-mathematics

I am trying to figure out the equations y=f(x) of the red dashed lines in this log-linear graph where the x values were plotted on a logarithmic scale while the y values were kept linear.

[image]

I tried to figure it out from the table below which revealed a geometric serie starting from the third X value (i.e x=25) but I am not sure how i can utilize mathematica to resolve this issue.

.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the incidence data from your table:

```
loglinIncidence = {Log10[#1], #2} & @@@
   Transpose@{{5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200}, {1, 1.11, 1.27, 1.4, 1.55, 1.71}};
model = LinearModelFit[loglinIncidence, {1, x}, x]

Plot[
 model[x], {x, Log10[5], Log10[200]},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[transformedData]}
]
```

[image: model]

[image: plot]

One should then be able to do the same with the mortality data set to get your second equation.

Comment: @MarcoB.Thank you so much!

Comment: @PureFunction Glad to help!